# Proof of $e^{\ln(x)\ln(2)}$, which natural logarithm do I bring down?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm currently stumped with the proof for the following problem:

$$F(x) = 2^{\ln(x)}$$
$$\Rightarrow F(x) = y$$
$$y = 2^{\ln(x)}$$
$$\ln(y) = \ln(2^{\ln(x)})$$
$$\ln(y) = \ln(x)\cdot\ln(2)$$
$$y = e^{\ln(x)\cdot\ln(2)}$$

Now, how do I know which natural logarithm to bring down?
What ensures that my answer must be $2^{\ln(x)}$ instead of $x^{\ln(2)}$?

Thanks! :)

Comment: $2^{\ln x}$ and $x^{\ln 2}$ are the same function.

Comment: That explains it! Haha thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same:
$$
2^{\log(x)}=e^{\log(x)\log(2)}=x^{\log(2)}
$$